# Bind different event to each dynamically created UL list item

Tags: jquery, html

I have an unordered list with several static list items that also has dynamic list items added based upon the presence of database content.

```
<nav id="main-navigation">
    <ul class="top-level">
        <li id="btnMap"><a href="#" title="Click to view map">Map</a></li>
        <li id="btnCity"><a href="#" title="Click to view cities">City</a></li>
        <li id="btnCounty"><a href="#" title="Click to view counties">County</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Each of the above static list items have their own function call - bound at run time like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnCity', function (event) { MEECTR.ShowCity(); });
```

The dynamic list items are added to the UL via a function call which is working:

```
MEECTR.AddNewLIElement(".top-level", "#btnMsg", "Click to view messages", "Alerts");
$("#btnMsg").css("display", "inline-block");
```

After the items are added, I am adding the events. However even though I am trying to assign different events to each new list item, they both seem to get whatever is the last added event.  Here is the code for adding the events:

```
$(".top-level li").on("click", $('btnMsg').attr('id'), function () {
        MEECTR.ShowMsg();
  });

$('top-level li').on("click", $('btnStreet').attr('id'), function () {
         MEECTR.ShowStreetMsg();
 });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain `$('btnMsg').attr('id')`? The selector doesn't seem correct (unless you have HTML elements like `<btnMsg>`), but moreso, it looks like you're trying to look up an element by ID, to grab its ID. Also, if you're delegating the events, your click events should not be attached to the dynamically-added elements, but instead a common parent. Attaching the click events to the items that are being dynamically added subverts the purpose of event delegation.

Comment: Yes, trying to get the ID as $('#btnMsg') did not work.

Comment: So I would need to add a generic function and within that, find out which element was clicked and then do work?

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to maintain if you added the item-specific method to each respective element. Here's an example with a `data-` attribute:

```js
// Stubbing this global object so that the example works.
var MEECTR = {
  ShowMap: () => console.log("show map!"),
  ShowCity: () => console.log("show city!"),
  ShowCounty: () => console.log("show county!"),
  ShowMessages: () => console.log("show messages!")
}

$(".top-level").on("click", "li", function() {
  // Get function name from the element that was clicked.
  var meectrFunction = $(this).attr("data-meectr");
  MEECTR[meectrFunction](); // Invoke the function.
});

setTimeout(() => {
  // Dynamically adding another menu item 3 seconds after load.
  $(".top-level").append("<li data-meectr='ShowMessages'><a href='#' title='Click to view messages'>Alerts</a></li>");
}, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="main-navigation">
  <ul class="top-level">
    <li data-meectr="ShowMap"><a href="#" title="Click to view map">Map</a></li>
    <li data-meectr="ShowCity"><a href="#" title="Click to view cities">City</a></li>
    <li data-meectr="ShowCounty"><a href="#" title="Click to view counties">County</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

You can provide dynamically inserted elements with a `data-meectr` attribute and leverage the same event handler.